# Update UITableView titleForFooterInSection for UISlider's valueChanged?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uislider

I have a UITableViewCell which has a UISlider in it. I have a footer text for the tableview that I would like to update with the value of the UISlider.

However, calling [self.tableView reloadData]; does not work for the UISlider, as it is too many calls. I am able to update the cell correctly (it also shows the value), but I am unable to update the footer text. I have tried:

```
[self tableView:self.tableView titleForFooterInSection:0];
```

But it doesn't work..

Answer (score 4):

Connect your slider to an action method in your controller:

```
[theSlider addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(adjustSliderValue:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Implement the slider action method:

```
- (void) adjustSliderValue: (UISlider *) slider
{
    // Change controller's state here. 
    // The next line will trigger -tableView:titleForFooterInSection:
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex: mySectionIndex] 
                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

This is more efficient than reloading the whole table. Unfortunately, there is no way to set a section footer text directly.

Comment: That doesn't work. It's the same issue as described in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252781/uislider-update-inside-uitableviewcell -- I can update the cell's textLabel, but updating the  section or tableView to update the footer does not work.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. OK, it looks like you have to implement -tableView:viewForFooterInSection: instead. That way the view is completely under your control and you can interact with it directly, without reloading data. To avoid memory-related issues while scrolling make it a retained ivar in your controller. The view may be of any UIView subclass, including UILabel.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Hey if you can write that as an answer I'll mark it as the correct answer so you get points or whatever :)

Comment: I'm able to update the footer title simply using [self tableView:self.tableView titleForFooterInSection:kSECTION]. I'm calling this on a seg controller tap. Works.